# ¿Por qué la clase String se puede usar sin constructores?

Tags: java, string

¿Por qué la clase `String` se puede usar sin constructores?
Investigando en *Google* y en la documentación de *Oracle* no encuentro una respuesta.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) . Está bien que recurras a la comunidad para preguntar y recibir propuestas que ayuden a responder tu inquietud, pero para que la respuesta pueda ser de buena calidad y logre responder tu inquietud necesitamos que nos expliques mejor tu problema e incluir algún ejemplo de lo que necesitas, explica detalladamente tu inquietud. Incluye por favor el código escrito en la pregunta. Te recomiendo leer este artículo: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

En Java, la clase String es inmutable y cada literal (Ej "123") es tomada como una instancia de la clase.

Directo de la documentación de la clase String:

> public String() Initializes a newly created String object so that it
>   represents an empty character sequence. Note that use of this
>   constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

En resumen, al dar un valor a una variable String, al mismo tiempo se esta instanciando, lo que hace que no se necesite llamar explicitamente al constructor.

Comment: No solo porque es inmutable, porque si tu defines una clase igualmente inmutable la JVM no tendría la capacidad de crear objetos de ella utilizando un literal.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que, como la clase String es inmutable, la JVM maneja un String-Constant-Pool, que no es otra cosa que una listado de instancias de String cuyos valores son diferentes. Por tal motivo, y el compilador sabe que cuando encuentre un literal de String (ej. "Pedro") incluirá en el bytecode la directiva correspondiente para crear una instancia de la clase con dicho literal como valor y meterlo en el Pool.

Para esta clase

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hola mundo";
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

El bytecode que se genera es el siguiente. Fijarse en el comando **ldc** que es el que indica que sea haga este procedimiento

```
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String Hola mundo
       2: astore_1
       3: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       6: aload_1
       7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      10: return
}
```

Este es el mismo mecanismo que se aplica con los tipos primitivos como `int`, `float`, `double`, etc. Así que del mismo modo que el lenguaje asume que en `int num = 5;` el literal 5 es el valor de la variable, en `String name = "Pepe";` Pepe es el valor de la variable. Con la única diferencia que al ser una variable de tipo String, la propia JVM es la encargada de crear el objeto.

Esto lo podemos ver en la especificación oficial de la JVM.

> **3.4 Accessing the Run-Time Constant Pool**
>   Many numeric constants, as well as objects, fields, and methods, are accessed via the run-time
>   constant pool of the current class. Object access is considered later
>   (§3.8). Data of types int, long, float, and double, as well as
>   references to instances of class String, are managed using the ldc,
>   ldc_w, and ldc2_w instructions.
>
> The ldc and ldc_w instructions are
>   used to access values in the run-time constant pool (including
>   instances of class String) of types other than double and long. The
>   ldc_w instruction is used in place of ldc only when there is a large
>   number of run-time constant pool items and a larger index is needed to
>   access an item. The ldc2_w instruction is used to access all values of
>   types double and long; there is no non-wide variant.